# How can I hide always select-container of select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, barcode

I' m coding in ASP.NET Core web application.
I have a multi select tag that its options are several barcodes.
I want user scan several barcodes by barcode scanner in this select input tag, but user can't see barcodes. After every scan select container will be opened and the scanned barcode does not show in input tag that user must scan this barcode again to select that barcode.

**In fact, every barcode must be scanned twice, to show in selected items.**
I guess, If select container opens never, then scanning does once.

How can I prevent this problem?

part of my view:

```
  <form id="Export" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BarcodeList" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="BarcodeList" asp-items="@ViewBag.Barcodes" class="form-control" id="txtBarcode" multiple>
        </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" asp-action="Export">Export</button>
     </div>    
  </form>
```

**Edit(More Explanation)**

In real world, user has several tags that a barcode is printed on every tag. He wants to scan barcodes of all tags continuously.

Currently he scan these barcodes in an excel file, and after every scan cursor automatically go to next cell and user doesn't need to do any extra work and with the most possible speed.

I want to simulated this in my code. I use multi select input instead excel cells (barcodes are limited and saved in database, so I populated select with whole of saved barcodes).

When user scan a barcode in select box, barcode is read and show in select box, but second scan cause to open dropdown menu of select tag (or select container), and user's scanning losts and doesn't read. In fact every barcode should be read twice.

I want to select container always stays closed, and never open that second scan doesn't cause opening this container. and every scan just read a barcode and show selected barcodes in select box.

Comment: sorry, but to be honest I can't understand your requirement well...

Comment: Which part is unclear? @TinyWang

Comment: I can't understand entirely...

Comment: @TinyWang I wrote more explanation at the end of my question.

Comment: sorry, I'm too stupid to understand it well. sorry again.. we may wait for some other communitors to share their wisdom...

Comment: Thanks, you're not stupid, probably you haven't worked with barcode scanner, and don't know about it.

Comment: let's wait for others' idea.